# Send Email in Android using the default android app(Builtin Email application)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send email from my application using the default android email app. I have written a code for that as

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mailIntent.setType("plain/text");
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { EMAIL });
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Invitation");
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,MAIL_MESSAGE);
startActivity(mailIntent);
```

But here it is opening the email application. I want to send the mail instead of starting any activity. Is there any ways to replace the startActivity and initiate the intent action?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact duplicate of this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a

Answer (score 2):

[this link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application) can be useful, have a look at [another useful link](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2011/07/sending-e-mails-in-android-using-intent.html) or a code snippet from [this link](http://blog.vimviv.com/android/intent-android/) is attached below

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, newString[]{"yourmail@website.com"});  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mySubject);  

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myBodyText);  

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail));
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can done it by configuring the mail code on server side and from android call web service then server will send the mail

http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/